# How to instantiate a certain subclass depending on an identifier, or is there a better way?

Tags: java, android, instantiation

**Background:**
I am currently working on a game, in which there will be several types of furniture such as chairs, tables or paintings for the player to interact with. For this I have created an abstract class `GameObject` that handles everything all these objects will have in common (such as drawing, holding position variables etc.). The furniture pieces will have a few parameters that differs, such as width and height (integers) and also what happens when the user choose to interact with it (for example: chairs -> if player is close, sit down, tables -> nothing, paintings -> examine independent of distance). Furniture can be created from a menu, that returns some kind of identifier for the selected piece (currently an integer).

**The Question:**
How should I implement the different pieces of furniture?
One way would be to create a subclass for each piece of furniture. But this has two drawbacks; First it will be hard to manage that many classes, and secondly when the furniture is created, the correct subclass of GameObject will somehow have to be created based on the identifier (see the followup question).

The most logical option to me seems to be to create a general class that takes the width and height parameters in the constructor as well as a runnable/other interface that can be run when the user clicks on the object. The different values could possibly be stored in a database and retrieved based on the identifier, but the problem still arises with the different actions, since the Runnables cannot be stored externally, and that leads back to the same problem as solution 1; Many different classes where one has to be chosen for the current object.

**Followup Question:**
Depending on the types of furniture and actions it seems possible that more advanced subclasses with additional methods might be required. If so, the problem of choosing which one to implement depending on an identifier remains regardless of the solution to the previous question. I don't want to use a gigantic switch statement to instantiate different classes, so is there any way around this?

*The game is for the Android platform, but there might be  future IOS port, so java-specific answers is not preferable, but acceptable.*

Comment: To create one of a number of classes based on param(s) have a look at the factory design pattern.

Comment: Why would it be hard to manage a class for each piece of furniture? It seems like a good plan to me.

Comment: It's better to have one class for each object, than to have all behaviours crumpled in one big class.

I would go with John's advice - factory design pattern

Comment: The factory pattern seems to be what I need to use. I'll probably write a "general" implementation of the furniture too that I can use for those that are identical except for appearance.

Comment: @Keppil: If I have >200 classes for different furniture and add an abstract method to the superclass, I would have to write >200 new implementations of that method.

Comment: Thiss combined approach sounds best.

Comment: @Jave: Yes. I still don't see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its really tough to come up with a perfect design solution for the problem without considering all the if's and but's.

However, one crucial part for your game is the relationship between the items (Furniture, painting, etc) and the actions that can be performed on each item. This is how you can model this relationship (Using composition ) :

Action : Interface representing a game action. Contains a a single method called performAction.

SittingAction : A concrete class that implements Action. Represents a game action for sitting. Implements the performAction method to define the code for performing the sitting action.

ExamineAction : A concrete class that implements Action. Represents a game action for examining an item. Implements the performAction method to define the code for performing the examine action.

Similarly, you can define one action per type of action that can be performed in your game.

GameItem : A class representing an item in the game. Contains properties common to all items such as item name, breadth, width, depth, etc and getters and setters for these properties. GameItem 'has-a' instance variable of type Action and a constructor that takes an Action parameter to initialize the Action.  GameItem also defines a method called onInteraction that you can call when the user interacts with a GameItem. This method will delegate the task of performing the Action associated with a GameItem by calling the performAction method on the Action instance variable. Therefore, any class that instantiate a GameItem must pass the appropriate Action to the GameItem constructor that represents the Action associated with the GameItem. When a user interacts with an item, just call the onIneraction method.

GameController : A class that listens to user events and calls the onIneraction method on the GameItem that was interacted with.

That's it. Clean and simple. No need for any if else statements to check what action to perform on what item. Simpy instantiate all your  GameItem instances with the appropriate Action instances and have your GameController that listen for user inputs call the onIneraction method on the GameItem that was interacted with.

Comment: Thanks for your input, this is pretty much what I've begun working on.

Comment: Glad to know this was helpful. ;) You could have a List of Action in GameItem if there is more than one Action associated with a GameItem. Just a thought!

Answer (score 2):

Forget about the generic class; you should make subclasses, as you presented in your first option. About your drawbacks:

> it will be hard to manage that many classes

Why? If you create subclasses you would do something like this:

```
GameObject chair = new Chair();
```

and if you follow the generic mode, you would do something like this:

```
GameObject chair = new GameObject(Type.CHAIR);
```

It is pretty much the same effort to create both, but you have much more benefits using the first one. The difference is that you can't handle different actions with the second approach without making a lot of conditional verifications. Also,  your core will be highly coupled with your existing objects, which means that you will need to change the core if you change one of the classes and vice-versa. With the first option you can do something like this:

```
selectedObject.makeAction();
```

and it will call the correct action based on the instance that it keeps. If you follow the generic approach, it will look like this:

```
if(selectedObject.getType() == Type.CHAIR) {
    //do char action. Notice that this ins't even a method provided by GameObject, you will need to get this from another place, since the GameObject is generic.
}     if(selectedObject.getType() == Type.TABLE) {
     //do table action
} if....
```

> when the furniture is created, the correct subclass of GameObject will somehow have to be created based on the identifier

I didn't get your point. You don't need to create based on an id, you just need to create the appropriated class. When you are creating the obejcts, you already know the object types, you just need to instanciate the correct class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what I meant with "hard to manage" was not using the classes, but rather writing them and/or updating them when needed. consider >200 different classes that has to be written/updated.

Comment: Concerning `you already know the object types, you just need to instanciate the correct class`: Yeah, I just didn't want to write a 200 clause switch.

Comment: What you can do in this case is create generic subclasses. Let's say that you have a chair, a couch and a bench; the action for them is sit, but something changes between them (for instance, the drawing). You can create a generic subclass and implements the sit action on it, extend this subclass and only implement the draw method.

You will write the sit action only once and you will have the three objects doing it, only changing the things that you really need.

Comment: About the switch, you don't need to do it. You can make a file that describe your scene (something similar to a OBJ file to describe graphic objets) and then create a factory to handle the objects.

And remember: the switch that you're not need to do in the instanciaton will be required when you will handle the actions if you follow the generic class approach.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I think I'll end up doing. I don't really understand what you mean with the file, could you post an example?

Comment: @Jave: If you need to update 200 classes to change some behaviour, that behaviour should definitely be in the superclass.

Comment: @Jave You don't need to create a scene on the code, you can load it from a file instead. This way you only need to call a "loadFile" method to get a different scene. You can define this file as you wish. You can do something like:

object: "Chair"
id: "myChair"
width: 100
height : 100
position: [10, 20]

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, but the user can place objects in the game, so they will have to be created as that happens. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely go with having subclasses for the differente types of furniture.

Instead of the menu returning an identifier, you may think on the menu returning the class name you need to instantiate (I suppose when displaying the menu you know which class will represent each of the entries). This way you avoid the identifier issue you are describing.

Regarding the actions that can be done on each piece, you can use interfaces :

Each furniture class will implement a set of interfaces depending on their posible actions :

```
Interface IExaminable {
  public <result> examine();
}

Interface IBuyable {
  public <result> buy();
}
```

and then you can easily check if an object is examinable with the isntanceof operator (if needed).

Hope it helps